# How do I set default namespace for c++ project in visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Good morning.

Sorry for the dumb question but it looks like the property page for Visual Studio 2017 is different from previous years in that I can not find an "Application" tab.  How can I set the default namespace for a specific C++ project in my solution?

Thanks in advance.